# Why Can't I assign a GameObject to the public variable of another GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the method in the player's script, it captures the enemy under cursor and create a missle to follow it.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10, 1<<8))
    {
        FollowEnemy missile = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation) as FollowEnemy;

        // runs perfectly, can change the value of hit.transform
        Transform temp = hit.transform;
        temp.position = transform.position;

        // enemy is a public variable(GameObject)
        missile.enemy = temp.gameObject;
        // and here comes "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
    }
}
```

FollowEnemy is the script on missile. Why can't I assign the `gameobject` I got to a public variable in another Class?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to instantiate your missile as `FollowEnemy`, but as `GameObject` which has the component `FollowMissile`.

```
GameObject missile = (GameObject)Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);

...

missile.GetComponent<FollowMissile>().enemy = temp.gameObject;
```

Comment: `bullet` is a prefab? Needs to be a gameobject assigned to a public variable and have the `FollowEnemy` script attached to IT.

Comment: It's fixed. Thank you anyway ^-^

Comment: +1 to Gunnar B.    @GunnarB. you did not find out the answer. Gunnar B. did find out the answer and his answer is exactly what you put as your solution. He said change the thing to GameObject and that solved your problem. It would be good to just accept this answer....

Answer (score 0):

After about 5 hours, I finally found out the stupid mistake:

```
public Rigidbody bullet;
```

which should have been `GameObject`